# Why is the flutter app not compiled on ios with the Adapty sdk?

Tags: swift, flutter, xcode, dart

I had this error when compiling my flutter application when working with the Adapty SDK (I have `adapty_flutter: ^2.9.3`, previously it worked without problems on version `^2.7.1`, but now it does not work at all).

```
Failed to build iOS app
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find 'reason' in scope
/Users/mdnlv/Documents/GitHub/up_doing/ios/Pods/Adapty/Sources/StoreKit2/SK2TransactionObserver.swift:70:15

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

What should I do?